# How to put text above other words in plainTeX?

Tags: plain-tex

I need to put chord letters above lyrics in plainTeX. The only thing I've managed to do is to place desired chord letter in a \hbox, which than I moved up using '\raise 10 pt \hbox{C}', for instance. But it looks terrible, I need the text below to be solid, without gaps. And it would be great if I could move that chord letter slightly to the left in order to put it exactly above the letter I need to. For instance, '... lyrics ly\chord{C}rics lyrics ...' should keep the second word 'lyrics' solid and put that chord letter 'C' exactly above the letter 'y' in word below. Is that even possible?

Answer (score 3):

Use `\halign`.

```
\def\chord#1#2{%
  \leavevmode % in case this starts a paragraph
  \vbox{% accommodate the alignment
    \offinterlineskip % disable the standard interline spacing
    \ialign{%
      ##\cr % standard template
      \hidewidth\fiverm #1\hidewidth\cr % the chord should occupy no horizontal space
      \strut#2\cr
    }%
  }%
}

lyrics l\chord{C}{y}rics

l\chord{C}{y}rics lyr\chord{D7}{i}cs

\bye
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. I really appreciate Your help

Answer (score 2):

Use `\rlap`:

```
\def\chord#1{\leavevmode\raise2ex\rlap{\strut\fiverm#1}}

lyrics l\chord{C}{y}rics

l\chord{C}{y}rics lyr\chord{D7}{i}cs

\bye
```